# Trying to parse csv file into array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have stored CSV files within my application. I want to convert it to an array of objects. 
I'm using csv-parse. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse

error message for just requiring the csv file

error:

> Ingredient #, Ingredient Description, Cycle Count
>              ^
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

```
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync');
const assert = require('assert');
const router = require('express').Router();
const count = require("./csv/IngCountCycle.csv");

router.get('/', function () {
    console.log("HI");

    const input = `
"key_1","key_2"
"value 1","value 2"
`;
    const records = parse(input, {
        columns: true,
        skip_empty_lines: true
    });

    console.log(records)
    //output ([{key_1: 'value 1', key_2: 'value 2'}])
});

module.exports = router;
```

test.csv

```
Ingredient #, Ingredient Description, Cycle Count
1,GUACAMOLE,Annually,
2,GUACAMOLE,Period,
3,GUACAMOLE,Weekly,
4,GUACAMOLE,Custom
```

testParse.js

```
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync');
const assert = require('assert');
const router = require('express').Router();
const count = require("./csv/IngCountCycle.csv");

router.get('/', function () {
    const input = count;
    const records = parse(input, {
        columns: true,
        skip_empty_lines: true
    });

    console.log(records)
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: you can't just require a csv in plain vanilla node, can you?

Comment: would I have to convert it?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra , (comma) on lines 1, 2 and 3 but not 4.  Your header line has 3 commas.  You either need to clean the data before using it or account for this discrepancy in your data with some code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like CSVParse is not being able to interpret your row delimiter. Could you confirm that you are using one of the supported options for row delimiter, as [specified in the docs](https://csv.js.org/parse/options/) (check option `record_delimiter`)?

Then, try to be explicit about which delimiter you are using, like below:

```
const records = parse(input, {
    columns: true,
    skip_empty_lines: true,
    record_delimiter: "\n"
});
```